# Redistributable Web Browser

Tags: licensing, browser

I'm looking to package and deploy a portable version of any popular web browser with my application, do you know any web browser that has a license that permit's to distribute it with a commerical application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much choice nowadays, so you can do your own research and read licenses for currently used browsers.

If you don't want to pay any license fees, you should take a look on Mozilla's Firefox licensing: http://www.mozilla.org/foundation/licensing.html
In general, yes, you can redistribute Firefox, under certain conditions. Also see Licencing FAQ: http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/mpl-faq.html

Or, take a look on Chromium licensing: http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/chromium/terms.html

Also, you might want to embed browser's engine in your application (For Mozilla's Gecko read:  http://www.mozilla.org/projects/embedding/ , for WebKit, consult your UI widget library, it might have it already; if not, take a look here: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki)