# Distributable Web Browser

Tags: browser

I want to distribute a web browser with my application, do you know of one that can be distributed without license issues?, i checked mozilla prism but no longer in active development.

Comment: As in as standalone general purpose browser? for what platform & can I ask why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redistributable Web Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689650/redistributable-web-browser)

Comment: just a lightweight browser, i want to ensure that the app performs thesame way and know if the browser is close so that the simple server that will be distributed with the app can shut itself down

Answer (score 0):

First thing: why would you?

Second thing: Tor distributes with modified Mozilla. By modified I mean: "trademarks" changed - Tor's Mozilla is named Namoroka and has a different logo. However, Tor is open-source. I have no idea if closed source would change anything.